# How to show custom view in bottom of the screen for entire application (like every screen) in react native

Tags: react-native, audio-player, react-native-flatlist

I am developing react-native project. I am new to react-native.
I have one screen, Which shows flatlist, In that flatlist showing each cell has some audio URL. Once user taps on URL, We have to show audio player bottom of the screen. And we have to show controls like play/pause/stop, progressbar, background wallpaper and track title.

Also, If user navigates to other screen and if audio player playing audio, I have to maintain this bottom audio player every screen.

I am basically from iOS development, In iOS we know we can defined this bottom view in app delegate class, But, In react native how to implement this and how to maintain this state of audio playing/stop?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using react-navigation?

Comment: Yes. We have sideview controller our application.

Comment: Are you solve it?

Comment: @OliverD No, I did not fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are using React Navigation, one approach may be to render a component outside of your app container. Something like this:

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
    ...
);

const Navigation = createAppContainer(Tabs);

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Navigation />
                <AudioPlayer/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Where the `<AudioPlayer/>` represents the play, pause, etc. at the bottom of the screen.

You can then control (show/hide/update status/etc.) this component through screen props passed to your app container or through redux depending on your prefered configuration.